# How to get hold of Connection object in spring data jpa?

Tags: spring-data-jpa

I am using HikariDatasource as connection pool with Spring data JPA.
How do i get hold of the connection object in my code?
Is there any way to do it? I need to unlock jdbc driver after I get the connection.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to extend HikariDataSource class and override the getConnection() method. Supply this wrapper class to the DataSource bean.